# Error installing eth-brownie with pipx: "No Python at: <Location of Old Python Installation>"

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, blockchain, ethereum, brownie

I'm trying to install eth-brownie. Followed the Brownie documentation and installed pipx, then ran *pipx ensurepath*. I was originally using Python 3.10 but couldn't install it, found that this was pretty common and the best fix was to downgrade to 3.9.

After uninstalling 3.10 and installing 3.9, I ran everything again. When I run *pipx install eth-brownie*, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\garri>pipx install eth-brownie
No Python at 'C:\Users\garri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\garri\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2022-03-28_13.40.53_pip_errors.log

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

I removed Python 3.10 from Path and *python --version* returns 3.9.12 as expected. I'm at a loss, as I feel like I've tried everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a pipx cache issue. You have to delete the following folder to remove pipx related cached files.

`C:\Users\<username>\.local\pipx`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just saw this, but I ended up solving the problem by reinstalling Python 3.10 just to run the command.

Comment: For me it wasnt enough to remove the c:\Users\<username>\.local\pipx folder. I also needed to remove c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\pipx folder. You can check the folder used for the cache by running
pipx environment